# Define custome header in ng-resource angularjs issue

Tags: angularjs

I using `AngularJS v1.5.8` and set the content-type to `application/json` as shown below:

```
 .factory('UserService',function ($resource) {
    var resource =  $resource('http://192.168.1.247:8189/api/Account/RegisterUser',{ },{
        save:{
            method:'POST',
              headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
        }
    });

    return resource;
});
```

and in my controller i have:

```
 .controller("MyController", function( $scope, UserService) {
    UserService.save({'cellPhone':'099999999'});
})
```

but it doesn't work, and the request is sent as 'application/xml' (i give unsupported media type. erroe:415). what is the problem?

Comment: what api are you using (maybe have a look in the webconfig of the api)

Comment: @stackg91 I using `Rest api`, and i should send data in json format to it. so i need this content type